# Why this question is off-topic and migrated to U&L?

Tags: discussion, migration

[differentiate between touchscreen and mouse inputs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203230/differentiate-between-touchscreen-and-mouse-inputs)

I've the same problem with Lubuntu 15.04, and I don't think that I should make the same question again.

I don't have any problem to address questions to other stackexchange sites, I'm just wondering about the criteria.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should look at some of the questions we get here: Most end users don't know the difference between Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Kali, Mint, Elementary, Red Hat Enterprise Linux and Windows. (And I've seen all of the aforementioned *and some more...*)

So: go ahead, [post your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), give as an absolute minimum the `lsb_release --short --codename&&uname --kernel-release`, explain what you have and what you're trying to accomplish and you're good to go!

## :-)

Answer (score 15):

You're right, the question isn't off-topic. It was as migrated to Unix and Linux only because the OP requested it in a flag.

Usually if you ask for your question to be moved we are happy to oblige, especially if you aren't getting a satisfactory answer here.